# How can I get my rating info into my database? (YII2)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

i've created a 5 star rating system which is working because when i click on the stars I get the notification message and everything saying "thanks you've rated 3 stars".

I wish to however put this rating info inside my database but for some reason nothing is happening. This is my code.

Javascript and AJAX:

```
$('#experience_stars li').on('click', function(){
    var onStar = parseInt($(this).data('value'), 10); // The star currently selected
    var stars = $(this).parent().children('li.star');
    
    for (i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).removeClass('selected');
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < onStar; i++) {
      $(stars[i]).addClass('selected');
    }
    
    // JUST RESPONSE (Not needed)
    var ratingValue = parseInt($('#experience_stars li.selected').last().data('value'), 10);
    var ratingPoints = ratingValue * 2;
    var msg = "";
    if (ratingValue >= 1) {
        msg = "You rated this " + ratingValue + " stars equal to " + ratingPoints + " points.";
    }

    responseMessage(msg);
    var url = "/index.php?r=admin/applicant/updaterating";
      // alert(x);
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            url: url + '&val=' + ratingPoints + '&id=' + <?php echo $model->id;?> + '',
            success: function (data) {
                //location.reload();
                //$(editableObj).css("background", "#FDFDFD");
            },
        });
    });
```

This is my controller:

```
public function actionRate($id)
    {   
        $model = new ApplicantRatingScore();
        $modell = $this->findModel($id);
        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
            $id = $model->id;
            
            //Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO ebs_applicant_rating_score(applicant_id) VALUES ('. $modell->id.');')->execute();
            
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $modell->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('rating', [
                'model' => $model,
                'modell' => $modell,
                ]);
        }
    }
    
    public function actionUpdaterating($val,$id) {

         Yii::$app->db->createCommand('update ebs_applicant_rating_score set score="'.$val.'" where id='.$id)->execute();
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The request should be sent with POST method and not GET. Also your update rating method contains terrible SQL which is just asking yourself for an sql injection attack. Please fix it asap.

Comment: @Bizley Still didn't work with POST.

Comment: Well, yes, you also need to send data with `data` and not in url. See [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). And since you are using model for retrieving the data on PHP side you will have to modify your `load()` like this `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')` so you don't have to add model name to all variables.